# Python3 + Nginx: Redirecting HTTP traffic to HTTPS on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed a Python application on Elastic Beanstalk using Nginx as reverse proxy server and uWSGI as interface between Python and Nginx.
The environment has been configured as single instance, so no I'm not using a load balancer.

I already have the SSL certificate, but I don't know how to configure it on my environment.
I need to install the certificate and redirect all the HTTP traffic to HTTPS.

I searched on the Web and found a few links on the AWS official documentation, but all docs are related to Apache web server.

Can you give me an help or a good reference to follow?

Comment: I have a [blog post](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2016/12/hosting-wordpress-on-raspberry-pi-part-6-implement-ssl/) on how I implement SSL for my nginx server might be something useful for you. It is on Debian-based server, so the directory, shell commands may not be the same as your environment, but the nginx setup should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps which I followed to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS in my AWS Elastic Beanstalk Go environment using Nginx. I believe it should be the same for Python+Nginx.

Created a file in the below directory structure in the root of the application code.

```
.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/00_application.conf
```

The content of the file was

```
location / {
     set $redirect 0;
     if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
       set $redirect 1;
     }
     if ($http_user_agent ~* "ELB-HealthChecker") {
       set $redirect 0;
     }
     if ($redirect = 1) {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
     }   

     proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5000;
     proxy_http_version  1.1;

     proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
     proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

For Apache, you should check out [this link](https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect/python/https-redirect-python.config).